# Amazon Connect Stop Call Recording

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

Is it possible to stop call recordings in Amazon Connect so the customer and agent can discuss sensitive material without being recorded?

I am aware of the *set call recording behaviour* blocks, but they don't seem to work on a call that has already been started with an agent with call recording enabled. Transferring to another contact flow with the recording type set to *none* doesn't seem to make a difference and the call carries on being recorded.

I am aware of the sample workflow *Sample secure input with agent* as outlined in this AWS blog https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/disable-recording-amazon-connect. This does work, however it relies on the customer entering payment details whilst the agent is on hold - preventing the agent and customer from having a sensitive conversation.

It seems the only way to stop recording once it has been enabled is to put the agent on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not know if you have not solved your issue yet, but amazon has update their Amazon Connect API that would allow you to suspend the recording.

Boto3 implementation

```
response = client.suspend_contact_recording(
    InstanceId='string',
    ContactId='string',
    InitialContactId='string'
)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/connect.html#Connect.Client.suspend_contact_recording

They have also allow you to Start, Pause, Stop.  (

We have just started to review this for a POC, turn recording off be default for a group of queues.  Allow to Agents to start and stop and pause recording as needed.

You can also read this in an Amazon Blog post that should be able to help you fully implement the solution.

[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/pausing-and-resuming-call-recordings-with-a-new-api-in-amazon-connect/#:~:text=is%20not%20recorded.-,End%20the%20call.,you%20start%20and%20stop%20it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/pausing-and-resuming-call-recordings-with-a-new-api-in-amazon-connect/#:%7E:text=is%20not%20recorded.-,End%20the%20call.,you%20start%20and%20stop%20it).

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with Architects at AWS, the desired and designed for solution is to have the customer automatically enter sensitive information with the agent on hold and call recording turned off to remain PCI compliant.

If that is not an option there are workarounds possible that go against the way Amazon Connect has been designed. **In order to turn off call recording once it has been enabled on a call, a new contact ID must be established.** To do this you would need to transfer the user to your external phone number again or transfer to a queue and disable call recording in that new flow.

This brings in extra issues around how to get the customer back to the original agent once the sensitive information has been discussed. It also means you would potentially have 3+ contact IDs for the same transaction, with call recording spread across them.